# TypeError: an integer is required (got type dict)

Tags: python

```
from clevertap import CleverTap
import json
import urllib
import time
import urllib.parse
import urllib.urlopen
import urllib.request
import requests
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib.request as urllib
clevertap = CleverTap('679-WZ9-1A1A','WFS-QOV-AAAA')

query = {
    "event_name": "Diagnostic landing page viewed",
    "from": 20211010,
    "to": 20211010
}

res = clevertap.events(query)
```

Getting below mentioned error after running this line in Python 3.8.8:

```
res = clevertap.events(query)
```

Please help me to resolve it.

Traceback:

```
res = clevertap.profiles(query)
fetching initial cursor
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-2e904aa027a3>", line 1, in <module>
    res = clevertap.profiles(query)

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\clevertap.py", line 144, in profiles
    return self._fetch_records("profiles", query, batch_size=batch_size)

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\clevertap.py", line 176, in _fetch_records
    res = self._call(headers_params=headers_params) or {}

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\clevertap.py", line 262, in _call
    urllib.request.urlopen(self.url, args, headers_params)

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1397, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1354, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1417, in connect
    super().connect()

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 921, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(

  File "C:\Users\Apollo247\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 793, in create_connection
    sock.settimeout(timeout)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type dict)
```

Comment: `query` is a dictionary but `clevertap.events` requires you to pass an integer.

Comment: ```clevertap.events``` is expecting and int value and clearly ```query``` is a dict.  what does ```clevertrap.events``` function expect as an argument?

Comment: Is it okay that you disclose your account and password?